# IIS7 Recover Default Website

Tags: windows-server-2008, iis-7, exchange-2007

So I deleted my default website by accident on a Windows 2008 server in IIS7. This is bad because I now lost my Exchange OWA virtual directories... users are not happy =(. Also lost my https certificate I'm pretty sure. So I'm hoping there is an easy way to recover all that stuff being that it's Windows 2008 and all...

Any help appreciated. I have no idea where to start or how to recover any of this stuff besides creating a new site called default website and then hitting the MS Exchange manual on how to install OWA from scratch.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I haven't dug into IIS7 much yet but I know that a backup of the configuration is maintained at "C:\inetpub\cfghistory\CFGHISTORY_xxxxxxxxxx". You can take the applicationHost.cfg file from the CFGHISTORY folder from before the problem occurred and dump it into the "C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\config" folder (take a backup or make a copy of the file first), restart the server and see if it restores the config to it's pre-problem state. You may have to stop IIS before replacing the file.